# How to filter Gtk.Flowbox() children with Gtk.EntrySearch()?

Tags: python, gtk, filtering

I would like Gtk.FlowBox() to display only children that correspond to the text inserted in Gtk.SearchEntry(), like a search filter.

I think it is possible to do that with Gtk.FlowBox.FilterFunc() and/or Gtk.FlowBox.set_filter_func() but I don't know how and found no example using these functions on the web.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- Mode: Python; coding: utf-8; indent-tabs-mode: t; c-basic-offset: 4; tab-width: 4 -*- 

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class FlowBoxWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(300, 200)

        header = Gtk.HeaderBar(title="Flow Box")
        header.set_subtitle("Flowbox filtering")
        header.props.show_close_button = True

        self.set_titlebar(header)

        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)

        search_entry = Gtk.SearchEntry()
        search_entry.connect('search_changed', self.flowbox_filter)

        scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolled.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
        scrolled.set_min_content_height(200)

        self.flowbox = Gtk.FlowBox()
        self.flowbox.set_valign(Gtk.Align.START)
        self.flowbox.set_max_children_per_line(8)

        # Fill flowbox
        text = ['ABC','A','BCD','TCUNF','GNCBC','JFABC','LDNAB',
        'JJVIC','HZACB','BESEI','VEISEI','GJBVV','abcii','fjbci',
        'fsefsi','aabc','fesfoo','fffba','jjfsi'
        ]
        for t in text:
            label = Gtk.Label(t)
            self.flowbox.add(label)

        scrolled.add(self.flowbox)
        box.pack_start(search_entry, False, False, 2)
        box.pack_start(scrolled, False, False, 2)

        self.add(box)

        self.show_all()

    def flowbox_filter(self, search_entry):
        def filter_func(fb_child, text):
            if text in [label.get_text() for label in fb_child.get_children()]:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        text = search_entry.get_text()
        self.flowbox.set_filter_func(filter_func, text)

win = FlowBoxWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I edited my question because I found how flowbox "set_filter_func()" worked. The problem now is that the flowbox doesn't display any child when I clear the Gtk.SearchEntry text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : instead of searching for the text in FlowBoxChild.get_children(), assign a name to each child while creating them, then check if text match with this name when filtering. It works fine, like that and FlowBox Children get back when clearing search entry field.

Here is the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- Mode: Python; coding: utf-8; indent-tabs-mode: t; c-basic-offset: 4; tab-width: 4 -*- 

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class FlowBoxWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(300, 200)

        header = Gtk.HeaderBar(title="Flow Box")
        header.set_subtitle("Flowbox filtering")
        header.props.show_close_button = True

        self.set_titlebar(header)

        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)

        search_entry = Gtk.SearchEntry()
        search_entry.connect('search_changed', self.flowbox_filter)

        scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolled.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
        scrolled.set_min_content_height(200)

        self.flowbox = Gtk.FlowBox()
        self.flowbox.set_valign(Gtk.Align.START)
        self.flowbox.set_max_children_per_line(8)

        # Fill flowbox
        text = ['ABC','A','BCD','TCUNF','GNCBC','JFABC','LDNAB',
        'JJVIC','HZACB','BESEI','VEISEI','GJBVV','abcii','fjbci',
        'fsefsi','aabc','fesfoo','fffba','jjfsi'
        ]
        for t in text:
            label = Gtk.Label(t)
            child = Gtk.FlowBoxChild()
            child.set_name(t)
            child.add(label)
            self.flowbox.add(child)

        scrolled.add(self.flowbox)
        box.pack_start(search_entry, False, False, 2)
        box.pack_start(scrolled, False, False, 2)

        self.add(box)

        self.show_all()

    def flowbox_filter(self, search_entry):
        def filter_func(fb_child, text):
            if text in fb_child.get_name():
                return True
            else:
                return False

        text = search_entry.get_text()
        self.flowbox.set_filter_func(filter_func, text)

win = FlowBoxWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```